# Linq to EF Search for a string that does not start with a Letter

Tags: linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I am using Linq to Entity Framework 4, what I'm trying to do is build a query that finds all supplier entities that do not start with a letter, typically these are numbers, e.g. "1st Choice" I thought this would be trivial and wrote this:

```
var letters = Enumerable.Range('A', 26).Select(x => (char)x);
var results = from supplier in All()
              where !letters.Contains(supplier.Name[0])
              select supplier;

return results.ToList();
```

Unfortunately this fails with the error:

```
System.NotSupportedException`
"Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Char'. 
Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context."
```

Irritatingly this same query works fine in LinqPad as a Linq To Sql query. How can I get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
var letters = Enumerable.Range('A', 26).Select(x => (char)x);
```

To

```
var letters = Enumerable.Range('A', 26).Select(x => ((char)x).ToString());
```

And

```
where !letters.Contains(supplier.Name[0])
```

To

```
where !letters.Contains(supplier.Name.Substring(0, 1))
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
var results = from supplier in All()
              where !letters.Contains(supplier.Name.Substring(0, 1))
              select supplier;
```